# Dimmer switch hook up

Tags: electrical

I have a new dimmer I’m trying to hook up but the house is very old and only has 2 wires from the wall.
Switch requires positive and negative and another one to 1 pole.
Anything I can do or do I have to run new wire.
Thanks

Comment: What make and model is the new dimmer?

Comment: Pictures of the switch wires will help.  What you are describing seems like what is called a switch loop, usually just a black and white wire from the light.  The white becomes part of the black(hot) at the switch.  Newer smart switches and some dimmers also require a neutral, and in most older homes it means a new wire.

Comment: Yes I think I need a new wire.